# Getting data from order works in template, but not in transaction mail?

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I am running this code in my Template file:

```
echo($_order->getDeliverydate());
```

It echo a date, doing that in my transaction mail, it stays empty:

```
{{var order.getDeliverydate()}}
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
{{var order.deliverydate }}
```

I hope its working fine.

Comment: Perfecto :-) ... now the only question is, how I could reformat the date. The current output is 2019-07-10, I want 10.07.2019